# How to pass the value of a pressed button

Tags: android

I was wondering how to pass the value of a button to another activity. I have a screen with 7 buttons, and each button shows different data from the SQLitedatabase. So I was wondering how I can implement that in the activity so that I can select different data from the database, dependable which button was clicked in the previous activity. I know I have to use Bundles and Intents, but I cannot find how I can implement that so that the Activity knows which button was clicked and which data to select. Thanks!

Comment: ... by start codind ... what have you tried so far? (and why there is vote limit?)

Comment: i have tried the samples below multiple times. It didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass the value of a pressed button

Buttons don't really have a "value". You could use the button's ID, though:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, YourOtherActivity.class)
                          .putExtra(YourOtherActivity.EXTRA_SOME_KEY, v.getId()));
}
```

This will pass the widget ID of the `Button` that was clicked in an extra (named `YourOtherActivity.EXTRA_SOME_KEY`) to `YourOtherActivity`. `YourOtherActivity`, in `onCreate()` or elsewhere, could call `getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_SOME_KEY, -1))` to retrieve the widget ID of the button that was clicked, then use a `switch` statement or some such to route your behavior as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set it with

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ACTIVITY.class);
myIntent.putExtra("buttonValue", BUTTON VALUE);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Get it with

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra("buttonValue")
```

Button Text

```
String buttonText = button.getText().toString()
```